# A cycle is an even permutation iff its length is odd

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, symmetric-groups

> Prove that for all pairwise distinct $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_t \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}, (a_1,a_2, \ldots a_t) \in A_n$ if and only if $t$ is odd.

How to prove the odd cycles of transposition will be product of even number of transpositions in this case

Comment: Induction on $t$? Direct construction? There are several ways.

Comment: For pairwise distinct $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_t ∈ \{1, 2, . . . , n\}$, let $(a_1\, a_2\, \dots \,a_t)$ denote the permutation
of $\operatorname{Sym}(\{1, 2, . . . , n\})$ that maps $a_1$ maps to $a_2$, $a_2 → a_3, \dots, a_{t−1} → a_t , a_t → a_1$, and $x → x$ for
each $x ∈ \{1, 2, . . . , n\} \ \{a_1, a_2,\dots, a_t\}$. Prove that for all pairwise distinct $a_1, a_2, . . . , a_t ∈ \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$, $\;(a_1\, a_2\,\dots\,a_t) ∈ A_n$ if and only if $t$ is odd.

Answer (score 1):

$(123\dots n)=(1n)(1n-1)\dots(12)$ for instance.  There's nothing special about $1,2,\dots,n$ here.Thus a cycle of odd length is even.

Comment: For pairwise distinct $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_t ∈ \{1, 2, . . . , n\}$, let $(a_1\, a_2\, \dots \,a_t)$ denote the permutation
of $\operatorname{Sym}(\{1, 2, . . . , n\})$ that maps $a_1$ maps to $a_2$, $a_2 → a_3, \dots, a_{t−1} → a_t , a_t → a_1$, and $x → x$ for
each $x ∈ \{1, 2, . . . , n\} \ \{a_1, a_2,\dots, a_t\}$. Prove that for all pairwise distinct $a_1, a_2, . . . , a_t ∈ \{1, 2, \dots, n\}$, $\;(a_1\, a_2\,\dots\,a_t) ∈ A_n$ if and only if $t$ is odd. I don't understand how to do the proof for this specific question

Comment: I essentially showed that iff $n$ is odd, it can be written as a product of an even number of transpositions.  Pair that with the fact that a permutation cannot be written as a product of both an even and odd number of transpositions.

Comment: Thanks. That's helpful